# Convert JSON file contents to Python list

Tags: python, json, string, list

My project requires a JSON file to remember a string of words. The code converts a list:

```
lst = ['Hello', ' there', ' world!']
```

Into a string on the JSON file. It does this by using the code:

```
lst = "".join(lst)
jsonFile = open("example.json", "w")
jsonFile.write(json.dumps(lst))
jsonFile.close()
```

New example.json:

```
"Hello there world!"
```

How do I then convert `example.json` back into `lst` as a usable list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would like to convert a string of words into a list:

```
my_string = "Hello there world!"

print(my_string.split()) # gives you ['Hello', 'there', 'world!']
```

Is this the output you were looking for? I suspect the additional quotation marks is because you might have typecasted the string again before splitting it into a list

Based on the edited question:

```
lst = ['"Hello there world!"'] 
output_string = ''.join(map(str, lst)).replace('"', "")
print(output_string.split())
```

Comment: `my_string.split()` is already a list. Also, by default `split` will split by space.

Comment: Well I need to then convert the string in the JSON file back into a list. How would I do that?

Comment: I see you have edited the question further. To answer it, would you prefer all the json contents into a single list? If so, you can read each line and append to a list. Else, you can have a list for every line in the json. Can you give an example of how the json file looks like?

Comment: A single list. I would want the list “lst” to essentially paste example.json into itself as a list of words. Does that make sense?

Comment: When you say 'JSON file' that means the file contents consist of key, value pairs. For eg, {name: "John Doe", age:"50"}. Going by your ask, would you prefer your list to be `lst = ["John Doe", "50"]` ?

Comment: Not exactly. I have my code to where it dumps a list as a string into ```example.json```. The original list looks like the contents of ```lst``` in the question above. I want to convert the string in ```example.json``` into a list exactly like the original list above. My question is how I would code my program to do that. Does that help?

Comment: `lst = ['Hello', 'there', 'world!']
print(' '.join(map(str, lst)))` Try this. Does this answer your issue?

Comment: I’m asking how I would extract the string from ```example.json``` and turn it back into a list that looks like ```[‘Hello’, ‘there’, ‘world!’]```.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list  Can you check this and apply the logic mentioned in the answer? This should help with your issue. Keeping in mind that your `example.json` file consists of strings rather than the typical dictionary as you mentioned

Comment: Thank you for that! That extracts the string from ```example.json```. The problem is that it converts it to ```[‘“Hello there world!’]```. How do I then convert that into a list of words and not contain the quotation marks?

Comment: `lst = ['"Hello there world!"']
output_string = ''.join(map(str, lst)).replace('"', "")
print(output_string.split())
` This is a quick fix.  It returns ['Hello', 'there', 'world!']. IMO, the solution isn't great, so I'll make it more nicer, but this should take care of the extra quotations

Comment: Thanks so much! I’ve been stumped on the solution for a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump `lst` directly to json, no joining needed:

```
import json

lst = ['Hello', ' there', ' world!']

with open('example.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(lst, f)
```

You can then load the list from the file:

```
with open('example.json') as f:
  lst = json.load(f)
```

In case you wish or need to stick to your original code to save the file, you can load it like this:

```
with open('example.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
  lst = data.split()
  #lst = [lst[0]] + [' ' + i for i in lst[1:]] #if you want to reinsert the spaces
```